# VBA Function Return string type mismatch error

Tags: string, vba, excel

I'm writing a macro in VBA for Excel 2010.  I feel as though I am missing something basic in my understanding.  I've filled a string array and iterating over the contents in that array.  The text in the array comes from an html formatted email message and has loads of non-breaking spaces.  I want to remove these and other non-printing characters so that my output only contains text.

```
    For Each str In stringArr()
        CleanString (str)
        If Len(str) <> 0 Then
            Cells(Row + 1, 6 + index) = str
            index = index + 1
        End If            
    Next str
```

CleanString() returns a string as return type, but str does not change.  I've tried:

`testString = cleanString(str)`

which gives a type mismatch error.  Any suggestions?

More info...

```
Function cleanString(sInput As String) As String
    Dim sResult As String
    sResult = sInput
    sResult = Replace(sResult, Chr(10), "")
    sResult = Replace(sResult, Chr(13), "")
    sResult = Replace(sResult, Chr(9), "")
    sResult = Replace(sResult, ChrW(160), "")
    sResult = Replace(sResult, Chr(32), "")
    Trim$ (sResult)
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean (sInput)
    cleanString = sResult
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of `CleanString`?

Comment: edited the question with more info.

Comment: The array may not have a String format. If you specify the argument for cleanString as ByVal sInput As String VBA will coerce a string type array into a string. CleanString (str) passes the argument ByVal, meaning you must assign the return value to a variable in the calling procedure, such as str = cleanString(str), but you must have declared str As String. You don't need Exit Function before End Function.

Comment: Thanks Variatus.  You've pointed to where the problem lies... to use for each, str needs to be var, but I want to do stuff with a string.  Closer and closer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the help.
Problem was with specifying that cleanString() required a string.
Changing it to cleanString(as Variant), means I can:

str = cleanString(str)

Thanks to Variatus